# cakephp rest api for logging in through mobile device

Tags: php, json, rest, cakephp

I have a cakephp app where a person can login and  authenticate himself. 
I need to make a REST api where when someone enters credentials through mobile, they are sent in json format as a post query to a URL in the cakephp app and that should return 200 ok or something positive as response if correct. My question is, do these two modules have to be in the same controller, or is it okay to make a separate controller with its own view for third party devices trying to access database?

Answer (score 0):

Working with REST, check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

For login, check section "Manually logging users in" in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html:

```
public function register() {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $id = $this->User->id;
        $this->request->data['User'] = array_merge($this->request->data['User'], array('id' => $id));
        $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User']);
        return $this->redirect('/users/home');
    }
}
```

To handle response, you can use:

```
$this->response->statusCode(200);
```

I also would suggest to create a separate plugin API to communicate with other devices using json. It will be easier to maintain your project.